# Why does the following code result in Segmentation Error(Core Dumped)? KnR C_2nd_ED_Exercise 3-2

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I was working on KnR C 2nd edition exercise 3-2 :

[I am coding in a ubuntu terminal & compiling via GCC]

"Write a function **escape(s,t)** that converts characters like newline and tab into visible escape sequences like \n and \t as it copies the string t to s. Use a switch. Write a function for the other direction as well, converting escape sequences into the real characters."

Question: I was getting 'segmentation error(Core dumpted)' after running the program and entering input.

I spotted my error and the issue is solved.

But I do not understand why I was getting the 'segmentation error,' and want to understand why.

Here is the code (within the bottom-most comment is the code 'before the fix' that was resulting in 'segmentation error') :

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #define MAXLINE 1000

    void escape(char s[MAXLINE], char t[MAXLINE]);

    int main(void)
    {
        int i=0;
        int c; 
        char s[MAXLINE], t[MAXLINE];

        while ((c=getchar()) != EOF) {
            t[i++] = c;
        }
        t[i] = '\0';        /* NULL to indicate end of str */

        escape(s,t); 
        printf("%s", s);        

        return 0;
    }

    void escape(char s[], char t[])
    {
        int i, j, c;
        i=0;
        j=0;
        while ((c = t[i]) != '\0') {
            switch (c) {
            case '\n':
                s[j++] = '\\';
                s[j++] = 'n';
                i++;        
                break;

            default :
                s[j++] = t[i++];
                break;
            }
        }
        s[j] = '\0';
    }
    /* Segmentation error occurred. the fix was adding 'i++;' 
     * before 'break;' 
     * ie. before fix: 
     * switch (c) {
     * case '\n' :
     *  s[j++] = '\\';
     *  s[j++] = 'n';
     *  break; 
     */
```

Comment: Without i++ you stop advancing through t, but not through s.

Comment: Make a habit of writing readable `for` loops with iterator increment at one single place, instead of all over the place. K&R sloppily written `while` loops from the 1970s are error prone and hard to read. Avoid reading K&R in general, it's both outdated and harmful reading.

Comment: Please don't edit your question with the solution. If you think that it is worth for future visitors, write an own answer, else delete the question. -- Please take the [tour] to learn how this site works. It is not a forum.

Comment: @thebusybee what are you referring to? I don't see the answer edited in the question. OP wants to know _why_ the segfault occurred.

Comment: I did not check the edit in detail. The source seems correct, and as the OP stated in a now deleted comment, the missing `i++` **is** in the source.

Comment: @Lundin Cool. I will keep it in mind as I keep coding. I have yet to find a more readable code as I have only read KnR so far.. haha. But it is good to know this.

Comment: @the busybee Cool. I didn't know there was a 'tour'. I read it and it seems very reasonable and efficient.

Comment: @stark Right. But, if I omitted the i++, shouldn't the program still run? (although not as intended).

Comment: you will keep writing past the end of s. When you go out of bounds of your program's memory it will segfault.

Comment: @stark Ah.. it makes sense now. Thanks for the answer, appreciate it.